# Execution plan for prepared statement with LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sql-like, sql-execution-plan

I was wondering if there might be a difference between the execution plan created for a prepared query whether the '%' in a LIKE predicate is provided initially or later. What I mean whether this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ? || '%'
```

and then setting the placeholder to the value you are looking for or doing

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ?
```

and then setting the placeholder to the value you're looking for plus the '%' suffix will result in different execution plans (with the assumption that first one will be more efficient).

In the first version, theoretically the database would know that what I'll likely be querying for is a prefix, and hence choose an index to do this, whereas for the second form, it is arbitrary and it cannot assume anything (that said, of course also with the first form I'm still free to put any `%` in there, so there would still be some fallback needed).

So might there be some performance benefit, especially on some heavily optimized commercial DBs, of doing the first one or will it not matter as both execution plans will be the same and need to do some extra preparation once the parameter is filled in?

Answer (score 3):

You do not specify the database, but the use of double vertical parts for string concatenation suggests Oracle or Postgres.

In any case, most database engines are smart enough to recognize this:

```
where col like 'pattern%'
```

as something that can be handled by an index on `col`.  I'm pretty sure both Postgres and Oracle do this optimization (as do MySQL and SQL Server and probably other databases).

The next part is speculation.  I would imagine that when substituting a parameterized constant into the string, the same optimization works.  You can check this by looking at the execution plans for such queries in your database.

If you need more sophisticated text matching algorithms, most databases have support for full text search -- and this can considerably speed such searching operations.

Comment: I intentionally do not specify any specific DB, as it was a generic question. And I would expect any DB to use an index for 'pattern%', the question is, will that decision be done at query preparation time for the first query and hence need less time during actual execution, or will it be delayed to execution time in either case.

Comment: @JanickBernet . . . That decision would typically be made during the preparation step.  Come to think of it, the "constant" you are submitted might have a wildcard in it, so the database engine would have to do more work to use an index.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. So it will always need some way to bail out if you provide a parameter containing more `%`s. My question essentially boils down to this: Will the first version allow the optimizer to create an execution plan, that is fully specified on preparation time, and then just use it on execution time (as long as the parameter doesn't contain any more `%`) *or* will it anyway always need to alter/augment the execution plan on execution time, hence being slightly more expensive.

Comment: @JanickBernet . . . And the answer to that question depends entirely on the optimizer and the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLindoff: I know, hence I didn't specify a specific one, I was wondering if *any* database might do this kind of optimization. Maybe this is a bit borderline to ask on SO anyway, since it's not a specific problem, just some general interest.

Answer (score 0):

A prepared statement which actually leads to a cached plan will never use any index for this, because it's not know what kind of wildcards are within the supplied parameter. Only if the optimizer decides not to use a cached plan (i.e. re-optimizes the query every time based on the actual value in the parameter) it might actually to use an index.

Comment: This isn't true in SQL Server. The plan can have an index seek on `column` with the actual range of the seek [determined dynamically at run time](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx). In the event the parameter has a leading wildcard the range is the whole index. This type of plan is more useful if the index is covering though.

Comment: @Martin Smith: In case of a covering index not using the index would be quite stupid, as it's usually much smaller than the table and thus scanned much faster. But I doubt it SQL Server will use it for a query like the one shown in the question.

Comment: I take it that you didn't click on the link in my previous comment which shows an example of exactly that then.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Of course I read your link, but the example was a covering index, `SELECT p.Name FROM`, not `SELECT * FROM`